# Jquery table sorter not working and disable all other javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added Jquery table sorter to my head.

When I add the following to my javascript:

```
                       $("table").tablesorter();
```

All of my other Jquery gets disabled and the table sorter does either work.

Comment: what devs tools are you using? I recommend firebug for firefox. if this "disables" all otehr javascript then there is an error. When javascript fails, it completely fails (might be from the point of the error on).

Comment: Can you show us your page header ;)

Comment: A part of my header: http://pastie.org/2416728

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to open firebug or the console on chrome / ie9.

You have a javascript error which prevents any further execution.

Probably, the tablesorter plugin is not loaded. (`<script ... src="wrong here" .../>`)

if it is, and your error is inside tablesorter.min.js, you can try to use the not minified version.

ALternatively, your table is empty. If I remember correctly, tablesorter needs a non empty table.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'tableSorter'

Comment: The problem was that Jquery got called twice, but the tablesorter does not work on the table. The table gets called with ajax, maybe that could be a factor, any doubts how to add the tablesorter functionality to all new added tabels?

Comment: double jquery is indeed very bad. For content loaded with ajax use `$( 'table' ).trigger('update');` as shown [here](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-ajax.html)

Comment: Still no sorting is added - I have added the thead and tbody

Comment: I will continue to do wild guesses, but are your cells content pure "text" (dates/string/numbers), or html elements? if they are html elements, you may wish to look into the [text extraction method](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-option-text-extraction.html)

Comment: I but the Javascript on the ajax page that gets called and that fix the problem